# Infinite RecyclerView inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I want a layout containing `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView`. But inside `NestedScrollview`, `ViewPager` doesn't scrolling with `RecyclerView`.

Comment: well one thing you can do is to just make ViewPager as the first row of your RecyclerView

Comment: but header is single column, and RecyclerView have 2 columns.then how can i set layout manager.

Comment: have you found a way to have infinite RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?

Comment: nope :) we can use multiple layout inside recycler view. i used that way

Comment: does anyone found a way to have infinite RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give fixed height to your `RecyclerView` depending upon the number of items in a list. Use the following function to calculate `ListView` height.

```
 public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}

and

setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(recyclerView);
```

Comment: but i need infinite recyclerview

Comment: What do you mean infinite recyclerview?

Comment: adding elements on scroll

Comment: add the items on the list while scrolling, set the adapter and then pass recyclerView to the function. listAdapter.getCount() line in the above function counts the number of items dynamically.